# Populate datatable based on checkbox selection of a record from another datatable

Tags: java, jsf, checkbox, datatable, primefaces

I want to populate the roles datatable with the roles of the last checked database. How can I implement this?

```
public class Database implements Serializable {
    private List<Role> roles;
    private String name;
    private boolean selected;
    ...
}

public class Role implements Serializable {
    private String name;
    ...
}
```

**data.xhtml** looks like this

```
...
<p:dataTable id="databases" var="database" value="#{dataBean.databases}" >  
    <p:column>  
        <p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{database.selected}">  
            <p:ajax update="roles, databases" immediate="true" />  
        </p:selectBooleanCheckbox>  
    </p:column>  
    <p:column headerText="Databases">  
        <h:outputText value="#{database.name}" />  
    </p:column>  
</p:dataTable>  

<p:dataTable id="roles" var="role" value="#{dataBean.roles}" >                
    <p:column headerText="Roles">
        <h:outputText value="#{role.name}" />
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**data.xhtml**

```
<p:dataTable id="databases" var="database" value="#{dataBean.databases}" > 

<p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{database.selected}">  
    <f:ajax execute="@this" listener="#{dataBean.updateRoles}" />
    <f:attribute name="selRec" value="#{database}" />
</p:selectBooleanCheckbox>
```

**databean**

```
...

public void updateRoles(AjaxBehaviorEvent event) {  
    //database is theobject in the current row 
    Database database = (Database) event.getComponent().getAttributes().get("selRec");       
}   
...
```

Comment: How do I determine which record was selected?